# Expension file downloading shows finished download but no file downloaded in android

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

i am using APK Expension in android. i host my video.zip on google play as a draft. and i am using same step defined on google play for uploading app. Now when i want to download expension file , firstly it shows Looking for url to download then after 3 second it shows download complete but there is no file in my sd card. Can anyone tell me what is the problem.

Thanks in advance.